# (set-charset-priority 'unicode) ; should I do it?

Tags: unicode

I've seen the following in [some init files](https://github.com/hlissner/.emacs.d/blob/master/core/core.el#L69),

```
(set-charset-priority 'unicode)
```

but after reading the documentation, I can't really say I understand the  implications of this. In general I'm inclined to go Unicode and UTF-8 all the way, this being 2017, but would setting unicode as the highest priority charset have performance implications?

I know that a charset is distinct from an encoding scheme (e.g. UTF-8), but I don't think I understand Emac's handling of charsets well enough to understand the effect this setting has.

Currently, running `charset-priority-list` in my current Emacs returns a list of 170 charsets, beginning with:

```
(ascii
iso-8859-1
unicode
latin-iso8859-1
...
```

Comment: Good question. I too am interested in knowing the answer.